# Remainder on dividing $10^{n} + 10^{n-1} + ... + 10^{1} + 10^{0}$ by x

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given a positive integer $n$, consider the number $y=10^{n}+10^{n-1}+$$...+ 10^{1}+10^{0}$. I need to find the remainder when $y$ is divided by a natural number $x$.

e.g.

$111111$ $\%$ $2123$ = $715$

$1111$ $\%$ $7$ = $5$

How do I approach this problem?

Update: $n$ can be as large as $10^{20}$

Comment: Perhaps you need to give more constraints on what your process should entail. Because why not just compute $y-x\cdot{\left\lfloor\frac{y}{x}\right\rfloor}$?

Comment: @alex.jordan - This is a programming problem, but the naive approach is too slow. I am wondering if there is some theorem that could be helpful in breaking down the problem.

Comment: @Rayu if $\gcd(x,9)=1$ we can do it easily .

Comment: @hanu Yes, cases where x and 9 are coprime are being computed fast. I computed it as $(10^{n+1}-1)$ $\%x$ $* ModInverse(9,x)$. Python computes $a^{b}$ $\%m$ very fast as compared to first $a^{b}$ and then $\%m$, I dont know how.

Comment: Would it help if you used the identity $\sum_{i=0}^{n}10^i = \frac{10^{n+1}-1}{10-1}$?

Comment: @L'universo AS per what I know, it will help when gcd(x,9)=1

Comment: @Rayu the easiest way is probably to implement integer division and integer modulus in chinese remainder representation (CRR) and use the formula that L'universo gave you. It's not easy, but this sounds like a contest question which isn't supposed to be easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the order of 10 (mod x). To do this, you just find the least k such that $10^k=1$ (mod x), $k>0$. Then $10^{r+k}=10^r$, and you know the remainder of $10^n$, $10^{n-1}$ etc so you can just add them up.

Update:
If you have such large modulus relative to n, then using order will not help. $ord_{2123}(10)=192$, so unless $n>192$ you won't save any time using order (but with such a small n compared to the modulus, it shouldn't take very much time anyways). However, if you want to find $\frac{10^{21}-1}{9}$ mod 7, then it will save you a lot of time: $10=3$ (mod 7), & $3^1=3, 3^2=2, 3^3=6,3^4=4,3^5=5,3^6=1$, so $ord_7(3)=6$. This means that if $n=3$ (mod 6), $10^n=6$ (mod 7). The powers of 10 between 0 and 17 sum to 63, $10^{18}=1, 10^{19}=3, 10^{20}=2$ so desire quantity is 69 (mod 7)=6.

With large modulus that are products of small primes, you can use the Chinese remainder theorem, but this wouldn't work with 2123=11*193.

Comment: Can you show by example how this works on $111111 \% 2123$?